# Ti.App.fireEvent not working; error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'App' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, titanium, appcelerator

I have a simple Titanium app which opens a webview, and loads a URL. I want the links to open in the default browser, not the app.

I have some jQuery code which adds a click event to all links in the page.

```
<script>
jQuery('a').click(function() {
    console.log("Handler for .click() called for URL: " + this.href);
    Ti.App.fireEvent('ynOpenURL', {url:  this.href });
});
```

In the app.js file I have:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var mywebview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url :  'http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/',
    enableZoomControls: false   
});

win.add(mywebview);
win.open();
Ti.App.addEventListener('ynOpenURL', function(e) {
 Ti.API.info('yyyyyy');
 Ti.API.info(e.url);

 if (Ti.Platform.canOpenURL(e.url)){
  Ti.Platform.openURL(e.url);
   } else {
    alert("Cannot open URL");
 }
```

When I run the app on my Android (4.4) the web page loads correctly.

When I click a link on the phone I get the following in the console:

```
Handler for .click() called for URL: http://xxx.xxxxx.xxx/
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'App' of undefined (xxxx)
```

None of the Titanium console events are logged, only the javascript events in the webpage.

Comment: from where is the webview part loaded from, remote server url or html file within app ?

Comment: the webview is loading a remote URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that the webview is loading remote url. So **`Ti.*` or `Titanium.*` are not available at your remote server**.

What you can do is :

- Create a html file within the app and load the data via ajax and use `fireEvent`.
- Load the data via `titanium http client` and use `Ti.Platform.openURL` accordingly.

**Edit :** Quote from [Titanium WebView Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView)

> **Remote Scripts**
>
> Scripts downloaded from remote web servers cannot access the Titanium namespace.
>
> To interact with remote content, wait until the content is loaded, then use the evalJS method to execute a JavaScript expression inside the web view and retrieve the value of an expression.